# stopping propagation to appended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Updated:

I don't understand why this stopPropagation is not preventing bubbling.

http://jsfiddle.net/E6NS5/6/

```
$('#content').click(function () {
    alert('prop failed');
});


$('#wrapper').on('click', '.button', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('test clicked');

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="test" class="button">Top Button</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want the `.stopPropagation()` call in the event handler for `#content`, not `#wrapper`:

```
var test = '<div id = "test" class = "button">Test</div> ';
$('#content').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('prop failed');
});
$('#content').append(test);
$('#wrapper').on('click', '.button', function () {
    alert('test clicked');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/E6NS5/2/)**

Comment: Sorry (if I didn't explain well): you have it backwards. "test clicked" should show and "prop failed" shoould not not when a .button is clicked. I want the child element to run its function and the parent element to not. ie stop bubbling up

Comment: If you don't want 'prop failed' to show, then why are you binding it? Is this what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Arm9H/?

Comment: Because #content has a function to perform when it is clicked, and so do the buttons that are appended to it (note I am skipping the 'append' portion and just hard coding it as the example). I simply want the button to do what it does without firing the parent.. ! In your link when 'Test' is clicked only 'test clicked' should fire.

Comment: Did you see the fiddle in my last comment? The button fires but clicking on the parent div doesn't.

Comment: I don't know how to explain better. When "#content" is clicked, alert('prop failed') should fier. When ".button" is clicked, ONLY alert('test clicked') should fire, and it should not fire the "content" event. That is all I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that both events are bind with the "wrapper" class. In this example, the on key word will start with the wrapper class and filter the descendent rather than trigger the event for the .button - thus stopPropagation will not work [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E6NS5/3/) because they are both at the same level.

```
$('.button').on('click', function (e) {
alert('test clicked');

e.stopPropagation();
});
```

More information at [jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: I've edited my post. I still don't understand why it does not work.

Comment: stopPropagation stops the event from bubbling up the html tree, lets take the example in your jsfiddle - the event starts at the "most specific element" ('#content') then it continues to examine the parent elements in the html file firing event handlers that match. In your example it examines its parent '#wrapper' and triggers the event. In this event handler it contains the stopPropogation and will in fact stop examining the parent elements. If you put the stopPropogation in the '#content' event handler it stops examining the parents immediately [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E6NS5/8/)

Comment: How can I get it to start at a bound object?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question

Comment: I guess it is not possible to stopPropgation for live/on events.

Comment: yes it is, the only problem in your jsfiddle is that the first event handler fired is '#content' then '#wrapper'. Note that events start at the inner most element and move up the html tree. In your case .button, #content, #wrapper are run in that order. The "on" lets you select/filter a descendent to run the event handler in that context when '#wrapper' is being handled. In your example when handling '#wrapper' we search its children for '.button' and run event handler for each match - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E6NS5/12/)

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't matter in what order the event handlers are.

Comment: Priorities - 1. inner most to outer most elements 2. if you have two eventHandlers for '#wrapper' and one filters on descendent - this is run first 3. first come first served

Comment: And if I reverse the order, there is no difference. You should know that binding events doesn't have anything to do with the order they were bound in.